# Drawing a line by mouse in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, panel

I want to draw a line by mouse(interactively) , I used C# and WinForm, the line should appear at any time from the starting point(when the mouse press on the panel) to the current position of the mouse, exactly like drawing a line in **Paint** program.

but the code produces a lot of lines, i know why but i don't know how to overcome this problem

[image]

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Graphics g;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    Point p = new Point();
    bool flag = false;


    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = true;
        p = e.Location;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            myPen.Width = 3;

            Point p2 = new Point();
            p2 = e.Location;

            g.DrawLine(myPen, p, p2);

        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

}}
```

Any Help? i want to draw many lines and keep the code simple as possible!

Comment: I don't know much about C# drawing but I think the problem is you are not refreshing your canvas before drawing the new line.

Comment: The many, many evils of CreateGraphics().  Another one here, you draw the new line but never erased the old one.  Call Invalidate() instead and use the Paint event to draw.

Comment: @rendon Ok problem solved, but there is another problem when i draw a new line the previous line disappears!!

Comment: @HforHesham If you want to draw many lines you need a list that keeps the info of each line, then in your paint method call the `DrawLine()` method for each line in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to better manage the drawing.  Some pointers:

1. Don't use `CreateGraphics`.  Instead, use the `Paint` event already provided by the control.
2. Do your drawing in an inherited class of your own.  Don't draw in the `Form` class unless you're drawing *on the form*.

Here's an example class.  It's inherited from `Panel`.  Simply add this to a form, such as in the Form's constructor using something like `this.Controls.Add(new PanelWithMouseDraw());`.

**Note:  this uses `Tuple` which I believe requires .NET 4.0 or above.**  You could replace this structure with something else, if need be...you just need to keep a list of `Point` pairs.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class PanelWithMouseDraw : Panel
    {
        private Point _origin = Point.Empty;
        private Point _terminus = Point.Empty;
        private Boolean _draw = false;
        private List<Tuple<Point, Point>> _lines = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();

        public PanelWithMouseDraw()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _draw = true;
                _origin = e.Location;
            }
            else
            {
                _draw = false;
                _origin = Point.Empty;
            }

            _terminus = Point.Empty;
            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            if (_draw && !_origin.IsEmpty && !_terminus.IsEmpty)
                _lines.Add(new Tuple<Point, Point>(_origin, _terminus));
            _draw = false;
            _origin = Point.Empty;
            _terminus = Point.Empty;
            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                _terminus = e.Location;
            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var line in _lines)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, line.Item1, line.Item2);
            if (!_origin.IsEmpty && !_terminus.IsEmpty)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, _origin, _terminus);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me. One question though: How would i revert back to an event driven control. E.g.: i have a button on the SuperPanel, and it should draw the line in the same way you have here, but by only looking at the bool set? example: button_click = SuperPanel1.StartDrawing(Point StartPoint) then OtherButton_Click = SuperPanel1.StopDrawing() ?? Please help! :)

Comment: just so you know, i've asked my question, related to your answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720642/draw-line-between-point-and-cursor-location  ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix, change the method `panel1_MouseMove` as follows:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        myPen.Width = 3;

        Point p2 = new Point();
        p2 = e.Location;

        g.DrawLine(myPen, p, p2);
        p = p2; // just add this

    }
}
```

Keep in mind this will work with any mouse button down, left or right doesnt matter.

Edit1:

This should draw a straight line and all the previous ones.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public struct Line
    {
        public Point start;
        public Point end;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Pen erasePen = new Pen(Color.White, 3.0F);
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0F);
    Point p = new Point();
    Point endPoint = new Point();
    bool flag = false;
    List<WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Line> lines = new List<WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Line>();


    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = true;
        p = e.Location;
        endPoint = p;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            Point p2 = e.Location;

            EraseLine(p, endPoint, g);

            DrawAllLines(lines, g);

            DrawLine(p, p2, g);

            endPoint = p2;

            g.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // redraw for one last time...
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        Point p2 = e.Location;

        lines.Add(new Line { start = p, end = p2} );

        EraseLine(p, endPoint, g);

        DrawAllLines(lines, g);

        flag = false;

        g.Dispose();
    }

    private void DrawLine(Point start, Point end, Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(myPen, start, end);
    }

    private void DrawLine(WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Line line, Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(myPen, line.start, line.end);
    }

    private void DrawAllLines(List<WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Line> allLines, Graphics g)
    {
        foreach(WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1.Line l in allLines)
        {
            g.DrawLine(myPen, l.start, l.end);
        }
    }

    private void EraseLine(Point start, Point end, Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawLine(erasePen, start, end);
    }

}}
```

Comment: This will not produce a straight line

Comment: I get it, I thought you want to draw a sort of a polygon.